# Some issues with longtable, math coloumn, rowcolor and arraystretch

Tags: spacing, longtable, rowcolor

I have a `longtable` with alternating `rowcolor` and two math columns. The rowcolor works as intended when the content of the row is in a single line, with padding both above and below the row content. Some entries are valid for both columns and hence are in the middle. But overall the table is looking rather ugly :(

[image]

But if the content spans more than one line, or if there is an integral sign, the rowcolor touches the content and there is no padding. I have tried increasing `arraystretch` (its already 2 and does not make any difference) but it does not help. I have also tried `makecell` package as suggested in some answers, but that did not work as well, also did try `extrarowheight`. Another thing I tried is to manually add spaces after newline in each row `\\[5pt]`, but that only solves the problem for the bottom parts touching the next coloured row and its variable. In some cases I had to add 8pt or 10pt for a better look. The top part of the content is understandably not affected by adding space after the row.

Please suggest what can be done. Any other packages instead of `longtable` and any other tips in general to make the table better will be appreciated. Bonus if all entries in a given column could be aligned.

MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}               
\geometry{paperwidth=205mm, paperheight=236mm, top=15mm,bottom=20mm, textheight=196mm, headsep=5mm, left=15mm, right=85mm, textwidth=95mm, marginpar=70mm,marginparsep=5mm}                   

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\tbb}[1]{\textcolor{DarkSlateBlue}{{\textbf{#1}}}}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}p{4cm}<{$}}  %  math mode column

\begin{document}



\newgeometry{margin=15mm,inner=15mm,outer=15mm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0mm}
%invoked newgeometry to fit the table in the given space, otherwise in the twoside mode the table runs into margin for even pages

{\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\rowcolors{3}{white}{DarkSlateBlue!30}
\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}MM}
\toprule
\tbb{Relation} & \tbb{\text{SI}} & \tbb{\text{Gaussian System}} \\

\midrule
Relation between $\vb{D}$ and $\vb{E}$ & \vb{D} = \varepsilon \varepsilon_{0} \vb{E} & \vb{D} = \varepsilon  \vb{E} \\
Gauss theorem for vector $\vb{D}$  & \oint \vb{D} \, \dd \vb{S} = q & \oint \vb{D} \, \dd \vb{S} = 4 \pi q\\
Capacitance of a capacitor  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ $C = \frac{q}{U}$}  \\
Capacitance of a parallel-plate capacitor  & C = \frac{\varepsilon \varepsilon_{0}S}{h}& C = \frac{\varepsilon S}{4 \pi h} \\
Energy of system of charges  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ $W = \frac{1}{2} \sum q_{i} \varphi_{i} $} \\
Total energy of interaction  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ $W = \frac{1}{2} \int \rho \, \varphi \, \dd V $} \\
Energy of capacitor   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ $W = \frac{qU}{2} = \frac{CU^{2}}{2} = \frac{q^{2}}{2C} $} \\
Electric field energy density & w = \frac{\vb{E}\vdot \vb{D}}{2} & w = \frac{\vb{E}\vdot \vb{D}}{8 \pi}\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}

\clearpage
\restoregeometry


\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `longtblr` in `tabularray` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}
[
caption          = {title},
label            = {key},
]
{
colspec          = {X[1.5,l,m]X[l,m]X[l,m]},
hline{1,Z}       = {wd=.08em},
hline{2}         = {wd=.05em},
row{1}           = {font=\bfseries,fg=DarkSlateBlue},
cell{4,6,7,8}{2} = {c=2}{halign=c},
row{even[2-Z]}   = {bg=DarkSlateBlue!30},
cell{2-Z}{2-Z}   = {mode=dmath},
}
Relation                                  & SI                                               & Gaussian System                  \\
Relation between $\vb{D}$ and $\vb{E}$    & \vb{D}=\varepsilon\varepsilon_{0}\vb{E}          & \vb{D}=\varepsilon\vb{E}         \\
Gauss theorem for vector $\vb{D}$         & \oint\vb{D}\,\dd\vb{S}=q                         & \oint \vb{D}\,\dd\vb{S}=4\pi q   \\
Capacitance of a capacitor                & C=\frac{q}{U}                                    &                                  \\
Capacitance of a parallel-plate capacitor & C=\frac{\varepsilon \varepsilon_{0}S}{h}         & C=\frac{\varepsilon S}{4\pi h}   \\
Energy of system of charges               & W=\frac{1}{2}\sum q_{i}\varphi_{i}               &                                  \\
Total energy of interaction               & W=\frac{1}{2}\int\rho\,\varphi\,\dd V            &                                  \\
Energy of capacitor                       & W=\frac{qU}{2}=\frac{CU^{2}}{2}=\frac{q^{2}}{2C} &                                  \\
Electric field energy density             & w=\frac{\vb{E}\vdot\vb{D}}{2}                    & w=\frac{\vb{E}\vdot\vb{D}}{8\pi} \\
\end{longtblr}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As supplement to nice Clara answer with a little bit changed table layout:

- no newgeometry for table, table can nice fit in existed table layout
- bigger `rowsep`
- different way to "centering" of twocolumn cells

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}   % set desired page layout
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {title},
  label = {key}]{colspec = {Q[l] X[l,mode=dmath] X[l,mode=dmath]},
                column{2} = {colsep = 2em}, % <---
                 rowsep  = 5pt,              % <---
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
                 cell{4,6,7,8}{2} = {c=2}{preto=\hspace{8em},l}, % <---
                    row{even[2]}  = {bg=DarkSlateBlue!30},
                 }
    \toprule
Relation                                  
    & SI                                               
        & Gaussian System                       \\
    \midrule
Relation between $\vb{D}$ and $\vb{E}$    
    & \vb{D}=\varepsilon\varepsilon_{0}\vb{E}          
        & \vb{D}=\varepsilon\vb{E}              \\
Gauss theorem for vector $\vb{D}$         
    & \oint\vb{D}\,\dd\vb{S}=q                         
        & \oint \vb{D}\,\dd\vb{S}=4\pi q        \\
Capacitance of a capacitor                
    & C=\frac{q}{U}                                    
        &                                       \\
Capacitance of a parallel-plate capacitor 
    & C=\frac{\varepsilon_{r} \varepsilon_{0}S}{h}         
        & C=\frac{\varepsilon S}{4\pi h}        \\
Energy of system of charges               
    & W=\frac{1}{2}\sum q_{i}\varphi_{i}               
        &                                       \\
Total energy of interaction               
    & W=\frac{1}{2}\int\rho\,\varphi\,\dd V            
        &                                       \\
Energy of capacitor                       
    & W=\frac{qU}{2}=\frac{CU^{2}}{2}=\frac{q^{2}}{2C} 
        &                                       \\
Electric field energy density             
    & w=\frac{\vb{E}\vdot\vb{D}}{2}                    
        & w=\frac{\vb{E}\vdot\vb{D}}{8\pi}      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work with `twoside` option of the `book` class, on the even pages the table runs into right side margins. https://imgur.com/OUGpS9Q I have almost one-third of textwidth as margin, hence using the `newgeometry` option to fit the table into page.

Comment: @Damitr, you are not right. It works. The same as accepted answer. BTW, in question you not provide `\documentclass` options nor page layout which you use in your document. There is no way to confirm your claims.

Comment: I have `twoside` option mentioned in the MWE with the `geometry` specified please take a look at MWE in orignal question. You perhaps copied the code from the accepted answer, which is not the same as code in MWE that I have provided.

Comment: @Damitr, I dont undestood what is your problem.

Comment: @Damitr, I don't understand what is your problem. You can add `twoside` option` o my MWE (now I do this for you and move table to even page, that you can see that nothing is change in table) . However, if your table is longer (has more rows with multicolumn cells, than you should this noted also in code row marked by `<---` )added number of rows where they are) . Anyway, you accept another answer which also use this code line and you not complain about this, so I wonder, why I deserve attention with yours comment (and accepted answer not) ?

Comment: Because you specifically mentioned in your answer as the very first point "no newgeometry for table, table can nice fit in existed table layout" but it does not with my MWE. I had looked at several such solutions which did not work with `twoside` option, but work very well for `article` class, before posting my question which was very specific for this requirement. See the image posted in previous comment https://imgur.com/OUGpS9Q this is what happens to your MWE when used with two side option. So to say `newgeometry` is "not required" is not correct.

Comment: @Damitr, again, you not liked my answer, you select another, so please stop with your comments. My answer is as it is.  The are not productive for anyone.

Answer (score 2):

A solution based on `longtable` and `cellspace` for additional spacing.

There are a couple of corrections to what LaTeX does by default. Firs of all, I stretched the first row by adding an invisible rule. Second of all, in a row before the last, I reduced space, that would be taken by superscripts in fractions, by enclosing expressions in `\cramped` and `\smash`.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}               
\usepackage{mathtools}   % Required by \cramped{}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[column=E]{cellspace}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{physics}

\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\newcommand{\tbb}[1]{\textcolor{DarkSlateBlue}{{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}E{l}<{$}}  %  math mode column
\newcolumntype{L}{E{l}}
\newcommand\dstrut[1][1]{%
  \rule[-0.5\dimexpr#1\normalbaselineskip-1ex]{0pt}{#1\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip}}


\begin{document}
\begingroup
\centering
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\rowcolors{3}{white}{DarkSlateBlue!30}
\begin{longtable}{LMM}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\tbb{Relation}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\tbb{\text{SI}}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\tbb{\text{Gaussian System}}} \\
  \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{3pt}{0pt}
  \dstrut[1.5]%
  Relation between $\vb{D}$ and $\vb{E}$    & \vb{D} = \varepsilon \varepsilon_{0} \vb{E} & \vb{D} = \varepsilon  \vb{E} \\
  Gauss theorem for vector $\vb{D}$         & \oint \vb{D} \, \dd \vb{S} = q              & \oint \vb{D} \, \dd \vb{S} = 4 \pi q \\
  Capacitance of a capacitor                & \multicolumn{2}{E{c}}{$C = \frac{q}{U}$} \\
  Capacitance of a parallel-plate capacitor & C = \frac{\varepsilon \varepsilon_{0}S}{h}  & C = \frac{\varepsilon S}{4 \pi h} \\
  Energy of system of charges               & \multicolumn{2}{E{c}}{$W = \frac{1}{2} \sum q_{i} \varphi_{i} $} \\
  Total energy of interaction               & \multicolumn{2}{E{c}}{$W = \frac{1}{2} \int \rho \, \varphi \, \dd V $} \\
  Energy of capacitor                       & \multicolumn{2}{E{c}}{$W = \frac{qU}{2} = \smash{\cramped{\frac{CU^{2}}{2} = \frac{q^{2}}{2C}}}$} \\
  Electric field energy density             & w = \frac{\vb{E}\vdot \vb{D}}{2}            & w = \frac{\vb{E}\vdot \vb{D}}{8 \pi}\\
\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{longtable}\par
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `cellspace` looks interesting, I wil look into it

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[3,l]X[2,l]X[2,l]}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
\CodeBefore
 \rowcolors{2}{}{DarkSlateBlue!30}
\Body
   \toprule
   \RowStyle[bold,color=DarkSlateBlue]{}
   Relation                                  & SI                                               & Gaussian System
   \\
   \midrule
   Relation between $\vb{D}$ and $\vb{E}$    & $\vb{D}=\varepsilon\varepsilon_{0}\vb{E}$          & $\vb{D}=\varepsilon\vb{E}$         \\
   Gauss theorem for vector $\vb{D}$         & $\oint\vb{D}\,\dd\vb{S}=q$                         & $\oint \vb{D}\,\dd\vb{S}=4\pi q$   \\
   Capacitance of a capacitor                & \Block{1-2}{$C=\frac{q}{U}$} \\
   Capacitance of a parallel-plate capacitor & $C=\frac{\varepsilon \varepsilon_{0}S}{h}$         & $C=\frac{\varepsilon S}{4\pi h}$   \\
   Energy of system of charges               & \Block{1-2}{$W=\frac{1}{2}\sum q_{i}\varphi_{i}$} \\
   Total energy of interaction               & \Block{1-2}{$W=\frac{1}{2}\int\rho\,\varphi\,\dd V$} \\         
   Energy of capacitor                       & \Block{1-2}{$W=\frac{qU}{2}=\frac{CU^{2}}{2}=\frac{q^{2}}{2C}$} \\
   Electric field energy density             & $w=\frac{\vb{E}\vdot\vb{D}}{2}$                    &
   $w=\frac{\vb{E}\vdot\vb{D}}{8\pi}$ \\
   \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: With `nicematrix`, you won't see thin white lines in the colored panels, whatever PDF viewer you use (even if you use FireFox or DropBox...)

Comment: Unfortunately `nicematrix` as used in the response above does not support a long table spanning multiple pages. If there a way to make it work across pages please let me know.

Comment: You are right: there is no way to allow the tabulars of `nicematrix` to be broken...